# Random phrase over html tags in Firefox Developer tools?

Tags: html, css

Hovering over any pre tag gives me 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'. This is no where in the document or in my css file. I opened the same page on brave and nothing was there. I looked at another html file with firefox and it came up in the body tag. I even did a rip grep on all my repos to see if anywhere that phrase could come up and it did not. Where does it get this from when hovering?

[image: On pre tag]

[image: on body]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog):

> "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a sentence that contains all of the letters of the English alphabet. Owing to its brevity and coherence, it has become widely known. The phrase is commonly used for touch-typing practice, testing typewriters and computer keyboards, **displaying examples of fonts**, and other applications involving text where the use of all letters in the alphabet is desired.

The Firefox dev tools are just showing you what the hovered font rule looks like.

It triggers when you hover over a font file in the CSS, not when you hover over a pre element.

Comment: That sounds about right. lol Why don't they do that in brave or chrome?